# Auto Resizing NatTable in Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable

I am trying to auto resize my NatTable. I have few things :

1) My NatTable consists of only one column.
2) I am hiding NatTable occasionally.
3) The Part Control surrounding NatTable auto resizes on mouse drag. NatTable should also fit the size.
4) I have custom cell painters for NatTable Cells.

I tried with my bodyDataLayer(Which is based on GlazedListsDataProvider) :

```
    bodyDataLayer.setDefaultRowHeight(35); 
    bodyDataLayer.setColumnWidthByPosition(0, 100);
    bodyDataLayer.setColumnPercentageSizing(true);
```

But nattable does not show up at all. If I double click the invisible rows, I get required row. But natTable itself does not appear.
NatTable shows up only if 
       bodyDataLayer.setDefaultColumnWidth(SOME_VALUE);
Only default column width works.

I tried to add a Paint Listener to NatTable to initialize auto resize commands as suggested on Official Documentation. But it has no effect at all.

I tried to add

```
   natTable.setLayerPainter(
            new NatGridLayerPainter(natTable, SOME_VALUE));
```

with auto resizing of columns by position.But it also renders nothing. I am wondering how to resize my NatTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically `DataLayer#setColumnPercentageSizing(true)`should be sufficient for percentage sizing.

I can only assume that *hiding NatTable occasionally* has a negative effect, because that might lead to miscalculation of the percentage values. 100% of 0 is still 0.

Are you calling `NatTable#setVisible(false)` to hide the NatTable? In that case try to execute the following lines of code

```
natTable.doCommand(new ClientAreaResizeCommand(natTable));
natTable.redraw();
```

If that fixes your issue, please open a ticket and report that issue. In that case it seems we need to add a listener for `SWT.Show` or override `setVisible()` to execute these lines of code on visibility changes.

Comment: hm, I just tested with the examples application by adding a visible handling, but it works there without modifications. Have a look at the NatTable Example Application -> Tutorial Examples -> Layers -> Data -> PercentageSizingDataLayerExample. Maybe it gives you some hints. Or create a ticket with an example so I can verify the issue in more detail.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, doing Resize command worked for me. I was excluding the parent composite of NatTable while layouting.